# Load additional ag-grid table rows based on browser window size and/or scroll bar being scrolled down

Tags: scroll, lazy-evaluation, ag-grid, infinite

I'm looking to apply infinite scrolling to an ag-grid table with a large amount of data on page where 50 new rows will be added at a time based on the BROWSER height and/or scrollbar being scrolled down, instead of the TABLE size and/or scroll bar being scrolled down.

I tried `domLayout='autoHeight'` but that seems to only affect the table. **Note:** I will be using a large amount of data in this table and I'd like to do this using ag-grid properties and events, etc if it's possible to do it with solely ag-grid.

[image: scrolling]

I’d like it to function like this example:
http://intercoolerjs.org/examples/infinitescroll.html
See how the table loads more data as the user scrolls with the BROWSER scrollbar?

I need and answer by 4PM Mountain Time if possible.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Dave

Comment: Unless you edit your post - nobody will answer. I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the actual issue is). *Please edit your post accordingly*

Comment: I don't think we can support that sort of functionality in ag-grid.. The closest would be something like this... https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#pagination